# WPF Presentation Framework Exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue with my WPF application throwing the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
> PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The exception occurs inside the `InitializeComponent();` on the main window:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="NationStates_Telegram_Suite.MainWindow"
        Title="NationStates Telegram Suite" Height="475" Width="610"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
```

of the xaml. VS Gives me the option to step inside the dll and it is broken at this line if that helps:

`55F94E4B  push        dword ptr [ebp+8]`

I have commented out everything I think I tried commenting out all of the code changes I made to know avail. How does one resolve this?

Comment: Can you post stack trace and inner exception details, if any?

Comment: Does it happen at the developers machine, or only on distribution of the application? If it only happens on distribution you might want to check the presence of all references (assemblies) you have in your code. E.g. a namespace as `microsoft.qualitytools.Testing` isn't present on a non-developers computer.

Comment: What are the used namespaces and reference in your project?

Comment: Where can I find the stack trace and inner exception details?

Comment: When run from VS it throws the Exception when run without it the program just never appears.

Comment: I have not yet released a distribution and don't currently have access to another computer.

Comment: Show is the xaml on the page, in particular the bindings.

Comment: @har07 there was no "view detail" available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy to employ is to remove any bindings in the xaml and run until the problem stops.

There may be a race condition with a binding and initialization which is occurring.

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue I had a radio button selected by default with a binding on when it was checked. Fixed it by disabling the selected part.